# Implement or configure categorization of course search results in open edx

Tags: openedx

I have an installation of edx fullstack, eucalyptus release but cant seem to get around configuring multiple filter for the course search page. I am only able to get the defaults as shown below
the default configuration that I have:

[image]

But my requirement is for something advanced e.g as in the edx site see below
What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Any pointers to some doc or is this not supported in edx?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by activating the search capability. Here is the [doc](http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/edx_search.html)